# Unable to open Progressive Web App after adding to home screen

Tags: browser, chrome-for-android, home-screen-shortcuts

I'm running in to some very strange behavior when trying to use Progressive Web Apps (PWA) after saving them to my home screen.

Every time I try to open on, the OS prompts me to install Chrome (which is already installed). I've made sure that Chrome is up to date and I have even tried remove and re-installing Chrome, but the result is always the same.

Here is a screenshot of the prompt:
[image]

Here is a video demonstrating the behavior: https://youtu.be/yxclkaWVefc

Any help in figuring out what is causing this and how to solve it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance :-)

- Device: Galaxy S8+
- OS: Android 8.0.0

Comment: Try setting Chrome as your default browser (if it isn't already), or making the home screen shortcut in Samsung Internet instead? If all else fails go with the wonderful [Hermit app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.chimbori.hermitcrab) for adding web apps to your home screen.

Comment: Have you had this behaviour with more than one web app?

Comment: @owlswipe Chrome was already my default browser. I tried saving with Samsung Internet... and that does NOT have the same issue as Chrome. It works as expected in that case.  I have never heard of Hermit until today, it looks pretty neat.

Comment: @DanHulme yes sir. same behavior with any PWA I try (dev.to, Instagram, Starbucks, etc)

Comment: @Maurice It sounds kinda like a Samsung software-related issue then. You'd best stick to Samsung Internet or Hermit for this I guess.:)